# Why doesn't function execute on Document load?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to get coords through html's geolocation automatically on page load, but it isn't working.

```
 <body >
    <p id="demo">hi</p>

 </body>

 <script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    var x = document.getElementById("demo");
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}
function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
});
</script>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

https://jsfiddle.net/bushido/dozay2mo/

Comment: Check the answer (and the notes, they are important!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a syntax error.

This is the fix:

```js
var x;
$(document).ready(function () {
  x = document.getElementById("demo");
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
});
function showPosition(position) {
  x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="demo">hi</p>
```

> Notes:
>   1. You need to make sure you load the `jQuery` library.
>   2. The `getCurrentPosition` on modern browsers require you to use SSL (`https://`), so if your website don't have SSL it will not work.
>   3. The `x` variable was a local variable (therefor was available **only** inside the `ready` block, and not inside the `showPosition` function.

Comment: So I did have a syntax error and after i fixed that (thanks to you), the permission prompt comes up, but it still isn't putting the coordinates into the container. Edit: Browser has SSL (Firefox latest), works when I use $(document).on(click....

Comment: thanks so much friend, I should have seen that x was only defined locally and that's why it couldn't be accessed. Edit: of course it's the least I can do